# Why does this method work in the console after the data is loaded, but not when used with an event on an element?

Tags: javascript, ajax, addeventlistener

I've been trying to figure out why addEventListener doesn't work with this function. players.getRushingYards() works in the console after the data is loaded. I asked a similar question before weeks ago and got pointed to an issue referencing the 'this' keyword. I'm not even using this, so not sure how it applies. Am I not doing a needed callback or something? I try and copy the data over to an object named 'players', and after the data is returned it works in the console, but again, using the listener it tells me that players.data is undefined. If anyone can help, it'd be greatly appreciated. I've tried using plain functions and what I know about bind, apply, call, etc to no avail.

```
window.addEventListener('load', getStats);
let players = {};
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest
let output = "";
let txt;

// EXPORT AJAX REQUEST FOR STATS VIA MODULE
function getStats(e) {
  // const number = document.querySelector('input[type="number"]').value;();
  xhr.open('GET', `https://api.fantasydata.net/v3/nfl/stats/JSON/PlayerSeasonStats/2018`, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "api key goes here");

  xhr.onload = function () {
    if ( xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200 ) {
      players.data = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
      console.log(players.data)
    }
    return players;
  }
  xhr.send();
  e.preventDefault();
  return players;
}

players.getRushingYards = () => {
  output = "";
  sorted = players.data.filter((el, ind) => {
    if ( el.RushingYards > 0 ) {
      return el
    }
  }).sort((a, b) => {
    if ( a.RushingYards  < b.RushingYards ) {
      return 1;
    }
    if ( a.RushingYards  > b.RushingYards ) {
      return -1;
    }
  });

  sorted.forEach((el, ind) => {
    output+= `<tr><td>${el.Name}</td><td>${el.RushingYards}</td><td>${el.RushingTouchdowns}</td><td>${el.ReceivingYards}</td><td>${el.ReceivingTouchdowns}</td><tr>`;
  })  

  let headers = `<th>Name</th><th>Rush Yards</th><th>Rush TD</th><th>Receiving Yards</th><th>Receiving TD</th>`;

  let combined = headers + output;

  document.querySelector(".stats").innerHTML = combined;
}

document.querySelector(".rushing-yards").addEventListener("click", players.getRushingYards);
```

The data returned is objects in an array that looks roughly like this (typical parsed JSON object that's in an array - I took most of the properties out for brevity)

```
response = [{
Name: "B.McManus"
ReceivingLong: 0
ReceivingTargets: 0
ReceivingTouchdowns: 0
ReceivingYards: 0
ReceivingYardsPerReception: 0
ReceivingYardsPerTarget: 0
ReceptionPercentage: 0
Receptions: 0
RushingAttempts: 0
RushingLong: 0
RushingTouchdowns: 0
RushingYards: 0
RushingYardsPerAttempt: 0},
{
Name: "E.Elliott"
ReceivingLong: 0
ReceivingTargets: 0
ReceivingTouchdowns: 0
ReceivingYards: 0
ReceivingYardsPerReception: 0
ReceivingYardsPerTarget: 0
ReceptionPercentage: 0
Receptions: 23
RushingAttempts: 192
RushingLong: 0
RushingTouchdowns: 11
RushingYards: 1250}]
```

Comment: I think it may have to do with not declaring the variables before the event listener. I could be wrong, that may not be an issue... and I'm on mobile app so can't test easily. Try declaring and then calling the function

Comment: Are you saying that the console.log inside the XHR onload callback is displaying undefined, but `players.getRushingYards()` is able to read the data as expected afterwards?

Comment: No. Maybe I should have clarified a little more. When I type in the console players.getRushingYards after all the data is loaded (about 10-15 sec on my end) then everything renders correctly. When I try and do so pressing the button, it says filter is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Your are making an asynchronous(AJAX) request in `getStats` method, the `onload` method is executed once the response is received from server. So data received from the server is not available to your `players.getRushingYards` since it is executed before response is received from server.
What you can do is either pass a callback method to `getStats` and call it after you have received the data from `AJAX` like

```
function getStats(e, done) {
// done is the callback
// open XHR and set headers
xhr.onload = function () {
    if ( xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200 ) {
        players.data = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
        console.log(players.data)
    }
    return done(players);
}
// xhr.send();
```

or you can copy the code following your `getStats` method and paste it within `onload`.

```
xhr.onload = function () {
    if ( xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200 ) {
        players.data = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
        console.log(players.data)
        // code to process players object 
    }
  }
```

You can check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests) out for further clarification/reading.

Answer (score 0):

players.data is undefined in the event listener until getStats() gets executed. 
Could you try declaring let players = { data: [] } on the second line to see if you still have this issue.